# JQuery returning Uncaught Error: cordova already defined

Tags: jquery, cordova, visual-studio-cordova

I am developing a cordova application- I am using Cordova 6.2.0.

I am getting an Uncaught Error: Cordova already defined, when clicking on a button. When it is clicked some previously hidden components grouped by a common class name are made visible by removing the display:none style using Javascript.

The error originates in JQuery. I tried different versions of jQuery including the latest version. What is weird is the fact that JQuery code is not being used in the fired script. The page is not being re-loaded.

In the html I am calling these scripts:

```
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/platformOverrides.js"></script>

<script src="scripts/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js"></script>
```

Also in the html I have these 2 buttons:

```
<button onclick="ForgotPassword()" style="background-color: #f79629; border-style:none; width: 200px; height: 40px; color: white; border-radius:5px;">Send Reset Code</button>
<button class="hideTD" id="CPbtn"      onclick="ChangePassword()" style="display:none; background-color: #f79629; border-style:none; width: 200px; height: 40px; color: white; border-radius:5px;">Change Password</button>
```

As you can see the second button is hidden. This will be made visible again along with other components when clicking the first button.

This is the start of the JS function - ForgotPassword():

```
var username = document.getElementById("Username").value;

if (username != '') {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: ResetPasswordUrl,
        data: { username: username },
        success: function (data) {

            if (data == '') {

                var nodes = document.getElementsByClassName("hideTD");

                for (var i = nodes.length, n = 0; n < i; n++) {
                    nodes[n].style.display = '';
                    }

                alert("A code has been sent to your email address");
```

Upon clicking the Send Reset Code, the above code is executed. The for loop visits all the components whose class is hideTD and removes the display:none style. As far as I know there is no JQuery that should conflict; besides, the cordova is already defined error does not make sense to me.

Comment: Sorry for voting down, but there is no code provided.

Comment: Ok Let's add code :)

Comment: Code added. Thanks

Comment: what looks weird to me: I'd use the Jquery style to access DOM objects like: `nodes  = $('body').find('[class*=hideTD]')`, then go on `$(nodes).each(function(){$(this).css('display','none')}` (or something close to that if you look at JQUERY functions syntax).

Comment: The functionality of changing the visibility of the hidden components is working well with Javascript - am I right that my code is Javascript and not jquery?. Whilst using JQuery would perhaps be more neat, do you think it will fix the problem? In my opinion since Im not using Jquery, the error and the point of this question is less likely to happen

Comment: And BTW, when I say Im not using Jquery - I am referring to this particular instance. Yes, I need JQuery in my app.

Comment: I am used to JQuery, and don't use much JS core syntax when I can do it with some JQuery (hence my comment). Does it even enter the `ForgotPassword()` function if you add a `console.log(...)` at the beginning of the function? Is cordovaReady() event fired?

Comment: Sorry no time for chat. I know that in my Cordova, JQuery, JQuery mobile, projects, I do all the creation of the display thru JS (with JQuery) by manipulating the DOM. The index.html file is just used to implement the first page. Once my deviceReady is ok from Cordova, and JQuery is ready from JS, I load a bunch of file which carry Object and functions that I use to create UI (and UI Controllers). Any function() I implemented with `onclick` event of a button worked doing that way.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help and no worry about the chat as you might have noticed I clicked on that by mistake as I didnt even send anything. Yes the ForgotPassword() function is being fired, and everything is being executed within. The method on the web service side is being done; the email is being sent successfully. I did some console.logs and I noticed that as soon as the code gets into the function there is no problem but the error comes up as soon as the ajax call is executed. Any ideas?

Comment: So the problem could be in the 'success' function()? I would try a console.info(data) to see if what is returned in this object is as it is sent from the server side.

Comment: Ok I know what the problem is, will answer my question for other people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What fixed my problem, was adding:

```
$("#form_id").submit(function () {
    return false;
});
```

in the OnDeviceReady() method. This is because I have 2 buttons in the same form. I still can't explain the error 'Cordova is already defined'.